# FlatShading on colored custom geometry

Tags: three.js, shader

As soon as I push my own vertices to a geometry, the geometry is a solid color, instead of having colored shadows.

---

Applying this code to a `THREE.PlaneGeometry` called `mesh` gives the following shading:

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
// ..
THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x66e6b0, shading: THREE.FlatShading });
// ...
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
mesh.castShadow = true;
```

[image]

However, when I apply the same code to a `THREE.Geometry()` with *custom vertices and faces*, the geometry is solid black. How can I give the custom geometry the same shading as the plane geometry?

- I can use `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` but then there are no longer shadows on the faces.
- Using `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors` and coloring each face still gives all black.
- A `THREE.AmbientLight` gives color but then there are no shadows on the faces.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hpo8hpj/4/) of randomly generated faces that are all the same color. Instead, I would like them to have different shadows because they are different angles (as in the above image).

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @gaitat jsfiddle added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem of a geometry appearing all black will occur when *any **initial** coordinate of a vertex appended to the geometry has an undefined value*.

*Even* if the geometry is displayed, animates, and no errors are thrown, if an initial coordinate of a `THREE.Vector3` is undefined, `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial` shading will not work.

This problem is demonstrated in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hpo8hpj/4/), where the use of `undefined_variable` prevents colored shading, and just yields a solid color.

To handle this, initialize all vertices to arbitrary values i.e. `new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)` and *then* use the values of variables in `animate()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the shadows that would produce an effect like that but a z-coordinate. In your jsfiddle all your triangles are on the xy-plane so they all have the same normal. So their lighting would be the same. So if you make the call like this:

```
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100, Math.random() * 100));
```

and also `light.castShadow = false;` because it does not contribute to anything then you will get the variation that you want.

Comment: Good point! This fixed the fiddle but the problem persisted in my code (my fault). It turns out that the geometry was all black because a variable passed into an appended Vector3 was undefined.